# I need an elegant way to decode a series of codes into a single Excel cell

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

We have a cell that's filled with up to five comma delimited two letter codes. There are 20 possible codes. I would like to create a single cell that contains a "decode" of those two letter codes. Right now, I'm using a series of 20 columns to decode a single value (e.g., `=IF(ISNUMBER($A$1,"aa"),"Option 1"," ")...`) with a `CONCATENATE` to build the decode list in the 21st column.

There has to be a better way. Is there?

[image]

Comment: Can you use Text to Columns? This will split each value into its own column. Or when you say "a single Excel cell" do you mean literally 1 cell for all 20 codes?

Comment: Yes, I'd like to create a single cell with the decoded values. We never have more then five codes per cell, but up to 20 different code possibilities that I need to check.

Comment: Text to cols still leaves me with the issue of decoding "aa" to "Option 1", "ab" to "Option 2", then concatenating that to "Option 1, Option 2" in a single cell.

Comment: Ah I see. I think the only way to do this with normal Excel functions would be to nest a `SUBSTITUTE` function for every label. If you want to try your hand at VBA, this might be a good place to start: http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=29700

Comment: @AndiMohr...that looks like it'll do it! Thanks. I like it.

Answer (score 2):

I think the only way to do this using Excel's standard functions would be to nest multiple `SUBSTITUTE()` functions, like this:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,D1,E1),D2,E2),D3,E3)...
```

[image]

If you have many many possible labels you need to replace you might be best off using some VBA, or sticking with lots of helper columns, as you have been doing.